# Stata applying group1's info to other groups if group1 is the same

Tags: stata

Suppose I have

```
group1   group2   info
100     1       .
100     1       .
200     1       10
200     2       20
300     2       .
```

Then, for group1, copy group1's "info" to other group1s if group2 is the same.

So the result will be like this.

```
group1   group2   info
100       1       10
100       1       10
200       1       10
200       2       20
300       2       20
```

I tried to do this using bysort but couldn't think of a way to do this..

Answer (score 1):

The question is puzzling because the example implies that the variable `group1` is irrelevant. I'll take the example rather than the wording as being definitive.

The solution by @timat is along the right lines, but does nothing to check a sensible constraint that non-missing values in a group should be identical.

One approach hinges on the fact that most `egen` functions ignore missing values to the extent possible. Hence there is just one distinct non-missing value if and only if the maximum and minimum in each group are identical (and not missing) and it can be copied to replace missing values within groups of observations. (If all values are missing, nothing problematic occurs.)

```
clear
input group1   group2   info
100       1       .
100       1       .
200       1       10
200       2       20
300       2       . 
end 

bysort group2: egen max = max(info)
by group2: egen min = min(info)
replace info = max if max == min & missing(info) 

list, sepby(group2) 

     +------------------------------------+
     | group1   group2   info   max   min |
     |------------------------------------|
  1. |    100        1     10    10    10 |
  2. |    100        1     10    10    10 |
  3. |    200        1     10    10    10 |
     |------------------------------------|
  4. |    200        2     20    20    20 |
  5. |    300        2     20    20    20 |
     +------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
bysort group2 (info): replace info = info[1]
```

Found solution here:
http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-10/msg00928.html